# normalise rows order php

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

how to order in a proper way the following structure with php: I have 3 tables

main table: `domain` related to `text modules`(foreign key fk_text_modules_domain_id ) and to `product modules`(foreign key fk_product_modules_domain_id) tables, each one has order fields to mark the order of the rows. I'm making to separate queries to filter the datas and after I'm merging the 2 arrays. My problem is: if the first tables order field value is the same as the second table orders value, the order of the rows are not rendering in a proper way. What should I change, how should I aboard this problem to get the best results.

```
+---domain----+

id   name 

1    example


+----text_modules----+

id   name     domain_id  position
1    example  1          1

+----text_modules-----+

1    example  1          1
```

how to normalise the values in the position column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is: if the first tables order field value is the same as the second table orders value, the order of the rows are not rendering in a proper way.

Well, don't use the same `position` then!

To leverage the DBMS to enforce that a `text_module` can never have the same `position` as a `product_module` (for the same `domain_id`), you can use inheritance to "extract" the `position` to a common table, and make it UNIQUE directly on that table. Something like this:

[image]

The `U1` denotes the UNIQUE constraint on `{domain_id, position}`.

*BTW, consider using natural keys (not shown above) - InnoDB tables are [clustered](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/) and secondary indexes are expensive.*

---

On the other hand, inheritance brings its own complications, so you might consider keeping your current tables and doing one of the following:

- Check if order is already in either table prior inserting a new row in either of them. In a concurrent environment though, this won't work without additional locking.
- Use a timestamp instead of `position`, if appropriate.

Comment: Whoa!!thanks a lot for this detaliated response. I'm going to revise it to can make some choises.